# AFNetworking lib not loading data from cache in offline mode

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am developing a content reading app in which some data is displayed in a tale view and respective detail views.

Now I have already completed the app but there is a small bug.

I am using AFNetworking library for online data load and offline caching.

I have defined caching policy as described by following code.

```
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"google.com"];

if ([reach isReachable])
{
    // Reachable      
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                  timeoutInterval:60.0];        
}
else
{
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad
                                  timeoutInterval:60.0];
}
```

But I am having a small problem that if I load some data online and then turn off the internet connection and close the app. 
And afterwords if I restart the app again in offline mode, the cached data should load but it is not happening.

I also have tried changing the caching policies as defined in the following link:
http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/02/20/afimagecache-vs-nsurlcache/

app deployment target : iOS 6.0

 devices : universal

 xcode version : 6.1

 AFNetworking lib version : 2.0

Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks in advanced

Comment: It can be really helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572050/load-offline-cached-json-using-afnetworking